# Odd Even Linked List

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, linked-list

I saw a problem on leetcode like:

```
Given 1->2->3->4->5->NULL,
return 1->3->5->2->4->NULL.
```

I wrote :

```
class Solution(object):
    def oddEvenList(self, head):
        oddhead = head
        evenhead = head.next
        even = evenhead
        while evenhead and evenhead.next :
            oddhead.next = evenhead.next
            oddhead.next = oddhead
            evenhead.next = oddhead.next
            evenhead.next = evenhead
        oddhead.next = even
        return head
```

but it says `time limit exceed.`

I saw someone's solution like:

```
class Solution(object):
def oddEvenList(self, head):
    odd, p= head, head and head.next 
    while p and p.next:
        odd.next, p.next.next, p.next = p.next, odd.next, p.next.next #insert 
        odd, p = odd.next, p.next 
    return head
```

Can anyone please explain why my code is fail in time limitation?

For the solution, can anyone point out how does that code work in specific? I am really not quite getting it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain why my code is fail in time limitation?

In the `while` loop you never modify `evenhead`, thus `evenhead` stays at node 2 forever and the loop never terminates. Surely you meant to have the assignments

```
            oddhead.next = oddhead
            …
            evenhead.next = evenhead
```

the other way round:

```
            oddhead = oddhead.next
            …
            evenhead = evenhead.next
```

- this way your code works.

> For the solution, can anyone point out how does that code work in
>   specific?

That solution is basically the same as yours - that `odd` equates to your `oddhead`, `p` equates to `evenhead`, the list assignment

```
        odd.next, … p.next = p.next, … p.next.next #insert
```

equates to your (corrected as above)

```
            oddhead.next = evenhead.next
            oddhead = oddhead.next
            evenhead.next = oddhead.next
```

and the list assignment

```
        odd, p = odd.next, p.next
```

equates to your (corrected as above)

```
            oddhead = oddhead.next
            …
            evenhead = evenhead.next
```

- one difference is in that assignment

```
        … p.next.next… = … odd.next… #insert
```

in the loop, while you have

```
        even = evenhead
        …
        oddhead.next = even
```

before respectively after the loop; this amounts to linking the interim last odd node to the first even node in each loop pass vs. linking the finally found last odd node to the first even node only once after the loop, of which the latter seems more efficient.

The only advantage of that other solution over yours is that it handles an empty list (`Solution().oddEvenList(None)`) gracefully due to the extra test `head and head.next`.